# RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded with array.slice

Tags: javascript, mergesort

Here I am trying to implement merge-sort with javascript but I am getting an error `maximum call stack size exceeded at array.slice`

```
function mergeSort(arr) {
    if(arr.length < 1) return arr;
    let len = arr.length
    let middle = Math.floor(len/2)
    let left = arr.slice(0, middle)
    let right = arr.slice(middle)
    return merge(mergeSort(left), mergeSort(right))
}
```

Comment: what does your `merge` do?

Comment: I think you have a typo: `arr.length < 1` should probably be `arr.length <= 1`, since an array of size 1 is always sorted. Otherwise an array of size 1 will still recur, overflowing the stack.

Comment: please provide a [mcve] that reproduces problem

Answer (score 3):

Recursion never stops.

When the function will be called with an array of length 1, this array will be split in one array with length 0 (there the recursion stops) and another array with length 1. The function will be called again recursively with the second array. This will produce the same situation again.

This means, you must handle the situation where the array has the length 1 correctly (as already stated by Raphael, sorry I didn't see this before). You can simply return an array of length 1 because there is no need to sort.